# calculate average runtime with pthread with weird results

Tags: c++, pthreads, runtime

So i wrote a program that calculate the average runtime of another program (name got from command line argument) with 20 trial runs. I used pthread to make the program run faster (running multiple trail in parallel). However, while the singlethreaded version worked great, the multithreaded version is giving me really weird result. Here's the code:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

struct Thread_arg{ // struct to hold the arguments
    int a; // index of which element for runtime
    char *b; // name of the program to run
};

double runtime[20]; // store all 20 runtime

pthread_mutex_t mutex1 = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* run_program(void *input){
    auto *arg = (Thread_arg *) input;

    high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
    system(arg->b);
    high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>( t2 - t1 ).count();
    runtime[arg->a] = duration;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
    cout << " Runtime: " << duration << "\u00B5s" << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);

    return nullptr;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(argc != 2){
        if(argc > 2){
            cout << "Too many arguments, you only need 1" << endl;
        }else if(argc < 2){
            cout << "You need 1 argument" << endl;
        }
        exit(410);
    }

    // format name of the program
    string program = "./";
    program += argv[1];

    int n = (int) program.length();

    char char_array[n+1];

    strcpy(char_array, program.c_str());

    // start testing, get average of 20 test
    pthread_t threads[20]; // create threads

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        struct Thread_arg *arg = (struct Thread_arg *)malloc(sizeof(struct Thread_arg)); // arguments in struct
        arg->b = char_array; // load struct
        arg->a = i;
        pthread_create(&threads[i], nullptr, run_program, (void *)arg); // launch thread
    }

    // join threads
    for (auto &thread : threads){
        pthread_join(thread, nullptr);
    }

    // calculate average
    double total_time = 0;
    for (double &i : runtime){
        total_time += i;
    }
    double runtime_ave = total_time/20; 

    cout << "************************************************************" << endl;
    cout <<"||| " << "Average runtime for program " << program << " is: " << runtime_ave << "\u00B5s" << " |||" << endl;
    cout << "************************************************************" << endl;
}
```

complie with g++ -o runtime main.cpp

test.cpp

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    usleep(1000000);
    std::cout << "Demo Finished";
    return 0;
}
```

complie with g++ -o test test.cpp

run with ./runtime test

The correct result should be:

```
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.01159e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.01040e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.01208e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.00862e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.0065e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.00863e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.01288e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.01039e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.01221e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.00687e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.01136e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.00874e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.03106e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.00714e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.00679e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.01873e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.01086e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.01146e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.01179e+06µs
Demo Finished   Runtime: 1.00995e+06µs
************************************************************
||| Average runtime for program ./demo is: 1.0114e+06µs |||
************************************************************
```

But instead, i got:

```
Demo Finished Runtime: 1011435µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 2024995µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 3033430µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 4039988µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 5046514µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 6059725µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 7071353µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 8081074µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 9088289µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 10099950µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 11108043µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 12126147µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 13134197µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 14151540µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 15161500µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 16173660µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 17186823µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 18194055µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 19206132µs
Demo Finished Runtime: 20217351µs
************************************************************
||| Average runtime for program ./test is: 1.06108e+07µs |||
************************************************************
```

As you can see, the time is compounding. Any idea why? I don't think it's the mutex since the common accessed variable is array, and none of them will access the same one.

Thank in advance.

UPDATE:
After trying it on a ubuntu VM, I got the correct result with the same code. However, I still don't exactly understand why the trail runtime result is compounding on MacOS. I think this might have something to do with `system()` or the fact that on MacOS, g++ is actually clang++. I will be doing some more experiment to isolate the issue. However, if you know what's going on, it's much appreciated if you can give me an exact answer.

Much thanks to @William Miller and @alk for helping out in the comment section.

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior, what are you running this on?

Comment: Are you sure you posted the "real" code, as it looks ok,

Comment: Not sure about g++, but gcc requires the option `-pthread` to compile a program using POSIX threads.

Comment: I've run the code in FreeBSD 10.4, Ubuntu Linux, and Windows 10 (Cygwin and WSL) and each time the behavior was as you described in what you expected

Comment: @alk g++ does as well

Comment: I'm running this on MacOS compile with g++ -o runtime main.cpp. I tired adding -pthread with same weird result.

Comment: @KerryCao Since it's OS specific I would guess it has something to do with how `system()` is being handled by MacOS

Comment: @william-miller I am going to try this on a Ubuntu VM. Also I wonder if `spawnl` will help since it's not as resource intensive as `system()` and does not reply on OS.

Comment: @KerryCao That's probably your best bet - if I had access to a Mac I would have tried to test on it as well but alas I do not

Comment: @Kerry, why don't you remove the mutex from `run_program` function and print the stored times in the `main` function instead? This probrably will not help, but will simplify the program and make reasoning about it easier.

Comment: @Krzysiek_Karbowiak that make sense since they are all just the same program running in parallel, no point to make it update live. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: the question has the tag: 'c' but the posted code is not 'c'!   Please remove the 'c' tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can repro it on Mac. The reason is that `system()` blocks if it is already running in another thread. It locks a mutex, internally.

All threads get to execute `now()` but then only one program gets to exec. So, that program gets a runtime of 1 second. Then the second one runs, but its timing includes the time taken by the first one and so on.

You can confirm it by adding:

```
20     cout << "before system()" << endl;
21     system(arg->b);
22     cout << "after system()" << endl;
```

So, the simplest answer is: because the system lib that comes with your compiler/system has a mutex to make system() thread-safe.

You can see the wait for that mutex in the waiting threads, inside `system()`:

```
* thread #4
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff6c8eda46 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__psynch_mutexwait + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff6cab5b9d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_mutex_lock_wait + 83
    frame #2: 0x00007fff6cab34c8 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_mutex_lock_slow + 253
    frame #3: 0x00007fff6c8688d1 libsystem_c.dylib`system + 183
    frame #4: 0x0000000100000e11 runtime`run_program(input=0x00000001003000a0) at main.cpp:21
    frame #5: 0x00007fff6cab5661 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 340
    frame #6: 0x00007fff6cab550d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 377
    frame #7: 0x00007fff6cab4bf9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
```

whereas the running one waits for the running program to finish:

```
* thread #2
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff6c8ee242 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4_nocancel + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff6c8689de libsystem_c.dylib`system + 452
    frame #2: 0x0000000100000e11 runtime`run_program(input=0x0000000100300080) at main.cpp:21
    frame #3: 0x00007fff6cab5661 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 340
    frame #4: 0x00007fff6cab550d libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 377
    frame #5: 0x00007fff6cab4bf9 libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely explains it. However, is there anyway to fix this issue by change system setting or do i have to rethink my implementation?